# Ubuntu phone Apt-get install not working

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch

I have purchase the Meizu mx4 Ubuntu edition and I downloaded the Terminal application from the store.

I wanted to try to install anything through the terminal but it's always the same answer:

```
W: Not using lockin for read only lock file  /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened
```

I tried to unlock the lock file with chmod but it says me permission denied. The file status in `cache/apt` does not exist.

Anyone can help?

Comment: You get English command outputs (e.g. for pasting here) by writing `LANG=C` before your terminal command: `LANG=C sudo apt-get update`. If you want your whole terminal session to be in English (until you close and reopen the window), write `LANG=C` as only command. - So it would be nice if you could replace your manually translated output with the correct English outputs. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root file system is mounted read-only. To solve that, you can remount it as rw, but you can really break your system that way. Use with care:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then try again:

```
sudo apt-get install your-package
```

After that, restart your phone to make sure it is mounted normally and you don't break anything.

So what are you trying to install anyway?

Comment: It works! There is a mistake in the first command line, it's remount and not remout. I installed python and sqlite3 for my work and they work fine!!! Thank you Maarten